# GO - Unknown error on executing a command via ssh connection

Tags: ssh, go, runtime-error

I'm trying to execute a command via **session.Run()** function over a ssh connection. So far I can successfully execute some commands but on others I keep getting the following error: **"Process exited with: 1. Reason was:  () exit status 1"**

```
func (p *project) connect(config *ssh.ClientConfig) {

    log.Printf("Trying connection...\n")

    conn, err := ssh.Dial("tcp", fmt.Sprintf("%s:%s", p.hostname.name, p.port.name), config)
    checkError("Failed to dial: ", err)
    log.Printf("Connection established.\n")

    for step := range p.typ.program.setup {
        p.install(step, conn)
    }
}

func (p *project) install(step int, conn *ssh.Client) {
    session, err := conn.NewSession()
    checkError("Failed to build session: ", err)
    defer session.Close()

    var stdoutBuf bytes.Buffer
    session.Stdout = &stdoutBuf

    log.Printf("Executing command: %s", p.typ.program.setup[step])

    if err := session.Run(p.typ.program.setup[step]); err != nil {
        log.Println(session.Stdout)
        log.Fatal("Error on command execution", err.Error())
    }
}


// That would be an example of a command which returns me an error
// "cd ~/www/www/ && git commit -m 'on the beginning was the commit'"
// That comes inside a slice on p.typ.program.setup accessed by the step(index).
```

The command output (session.Stdout) is the one i expect:

```
 "# On branch master nothing to commit, working directory clean"
```

And just to note I already tried to execute the command directly on the console and it works just fine.

So, the code seems to be okay, the command ran on the remote but I still have an error no matter what.

Does anyone have a clue about why is that happening?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not get the output of the shell command and see what the error was?

Comment: Well observed, i forgot about that. 

The output is: 

"# On branch master
nothing to commit, working directory clean"

Exactly what should be. But the error is still there =/

Comment: Then this the expected result, since git is returning with an exit code of 1. The same things happens in your terminal, you're just not checking the exit code.

Comment: I got your point and it seems correct. But doesn't that sound a bit strange? Exit 1 is an unsuccessful exit, right? Should I ignore this particular error message when i check the error?

Comment: This has nothing to do with Go, or ssh, it's simply that git exits with 1 when you try to commit when there's nothing to commit. You either need to check for something to commit first (maybe something like `git status --porcelain`), or check for this particular error and exit code.

Comment: Git returns 1 because you tried to commit and it didn't succeed do to no files being staged. You should expect that status in this case. If the commit were something that worked like `git commit -a -m "A message"` with one or more files changed then the commit would succeed and you'd get a 0.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe my library will helps in your case: https://github.com/shagabutdinov/shell; it covers basic cases of running ssh commands in one session.

Try following:

```
handler := func(outputType int, message string) {
    if(outputType == shell.Stdout) {
        log.Println("stdout: ", message)
    } else if(outputType == shell.Stdout) {
        log.Println("stderr: ", message)
    }
}

key, err := ssh.ParsePrivateKey([]byte(YOUR_PRIVATE_KEY))
if(err != nil) {
    panic(err)
}

auth := []ssh.AuthMethod{ssh.PublicKeys(key)}
shell = shell.NewRemote(shell.RemoteConfig{
    Host: "root@example.com:22",
    Auth: auth,
})

if(err != nil) {
    panic(err)
}

status, err := shell.Run("cd ~/www/www/", handler)
if(err != nil) {
    panic(err)
}

status, err := shell.Run("git commit -m 'on the beginning was the commit'", handler)
if(err != nil) {
    panic(err)
}

if(status == 0) {
    console.log("command executed successfully")
} else {
    console.log("command execution failed")
}
```